# Latent space of VAE

Tags: machine-learning, autoencoders

I have trained a VAE on a new dataset and it has converged nicely. I am able to interpolate between samples, etc, with expected results. However, when I randomly sample the latent space with `z = [np.random.normal(0,1) for _ in range(len(latentspace))]` I do not get the expected results. Looking at the data, I realized that while each of my vectors has ~ mean 0 and variance 1, if I look at real data, some positions consistently have mean > 0 or < 0. I was wondering if this is typical? I have seen articles saying to sample from the latent space by sampling from `N(0,1)` but as a result, this doesn't work.

Comment: Actually you missunderstood the consept the z is not directly equal to the N(0,1), it equals mean+variance*N(0,1) and then there are some other steps like KL divergence etc.